# TensorFlow training data Error. ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, valueerror

Im currently working on a tensorflow project and I am getting this error.

> ValueError: model_config not of type model_pb2.DetectionModel.

It happens when I'm trying to train my model. Has anyone encountered this issue before? First question asked on here so be gentle.

```
`Chinatowns-MacBook-Air:object_detection nathangrant$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7
  return f(*args, **kwds)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py:48: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 136, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/Users/nathangrant/Downloads/models-master/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 245, in train
    detection_model = create_model_fn()
  File "/Users/nathangrant/Downloads/models-master/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 105, in build
    raise ValueError('model_config not of type model_pb2.DetectionModel.')
ValueError: model_config not of type model_pb2.DetectionModel.`
```

Comment: I think it is version issue, support for ObjectDetection model was added to python3 later, may a fresh installation of Tensorflow can solve the issue.

Comment: what version of tensorflow you using?

Comment: Im using version 1.9. Should I update it?

Comment: instead , You can install tensorflow in a python 2.7 environment in that case you can avoid several compatibility issues.

Comment: this issue is also referenced here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1703

Comment: Yeah i looked there but isnt really a solution. Do you know what the error means? Like model_config is not a type of model_pb2.DetectionModel but why would that happen?

Comment: maybe its something with my config file?

Comment: i don't know about your config file setting though 
have you also tried using python 2.7 ? i had the same issue , and turned out it was compatibility issue and was resolved in python 2.7 .
hope that help

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the responses

Comment: Figured it out it was a combination of using python2, and my computer converting the config file into raw text with font and other weird stuff. Thanks for the help again

Answer (score 0):

Try this first,

**Solution A:**

1. Download this complete ["models_shareToPublic".rar file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hX4X6GI1iKvTUacarZwPycCcXCtGxd4_/view?usp=sharing).
2. Unzip/Unrar the file.
3. Copy all the contains of the folder to your project library directory
4. Run your code/program again.

**Solution B:**

1. Please open the cmd prompt in your project library directory
   In my case, it is: (my_project_name\venv\Lib\site-packages)
2. Clone the master branch of the Tensorflow Models repository by typing the cmd command below in the cmd prompt, which is opened in the specified directory above. (might take a few minutes depending on your network speed)

> git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

3. Move all the contents inside the **models** folder into the library directory stated in Step 1.
4. Create "*.pb2" files by following [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287910/16826713)
5. Change the import line below in ***model_builder.py***

Change from this:

> from protos import model_pb2

to this:

> from object_detection.protos import model_pb2

5. Run your code/program again, and you will notice this same error will be disappeared.

**Notes:**
If it appears

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

  Go to "research" folder and copy the "object_detection" folder to the directory same with "research" folder. So that it can call the library directly, if not, you have to adjust the import line in each .py file (very wasting time)

Hope it works to you too, Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

In my computer, I did these and fixed this problem:

In `model_builder.py`, don't use

```
from protos import model_pb2
```

use

```
from object_detection.protos import model_pb2
```

instead.